# Property changed transition effect with html `{{!! $html !!}`

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I'm trying to make a transition effect to text in **livewire** & **laravel**

It is working with `{{ $html }}`:

```
<p class="text-gray-600"  x-data="{show: false}" x-show.transition.duration.1000ms="show" x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true })" id="{{ $slide['current']['id'] }}c">{{ '<h1>hi</h1>' }}</p>
```

but it didn't work with `{!! $html !!}}`:

```
<p class="text-gray-600"  x-data="{show: false}" x-show.transition.duration.1000ms="show" x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true })" id="{{ $slide['current']['id'] }}c">{!! '<h1>hi</h1>' !!}</p>
```

Comment: Try not wrapping the HTML in single quotes

Comment: still not working @apokryfos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can't put an `<h1>` inside a `<p>` element. The browser will move
> it out.

so i must add it in a `<div>`

```
<div class="text-gray-600"  x-data="{show: false}" x-show.transition.duration.1000ms="show" x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true })" id="{{ $slide['current']['id'] }}c">{!! '<h1>hi</h1>' !!}</div>
```